# How can i create Stored procedure in mysql from python?

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedures, pymysql, stored-functions

I am trying to use pymysql to create a stored procedure in mysql database.
I have a file which contains the statements to create stored procedure.
I am running the mysql queries line by line using  `cursor.execure(line)`.
The Queries to create stored procedure runs fine on the db. But on python they are giving syntax error.

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `ipaybridge2`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `masking`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `masking`()
BEGIN
 
 query statements;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

the error i get is this: `` You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: 'DELIMITER $ $ USE `ipaybridge2` $ $ DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `masking` $ $ CREAT' at line 1 ``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pymsysql` does not want the `DELIMITER` statements. So you should already be connected to a specific database and thus the `USE` statement should not be required. Just pass the following to `cursor.execute` as a separate command:

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `masking`
```

And then pass to `cursor.execute` as the next command:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `masking`()
BEGIN
 
 query statements;

END
```

[See Error when trying to create stored procedure](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/98)